# How to add an onClick function that loads a web page with an image and text describing the image?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

For this problem I'm task with adding an on-click function to a carousel of 5 rotating images. When an image is clicked, load a web page with the image floating left with text describing the image. I'm lost completely.

The HTML and CSS I've done already, but I don't know how to add the `onClick` event, with the text describing the image. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the HTML and the CSS for web page:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

#stage {
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
}

#spinner {
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#spinner:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

#spinner img {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="stage" style="padding-left: 180px; height: 160px;">
    <div id="spinner" style="-webkit-transform-origin: 180px 0 0;">
      <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 160px;" src="images/truck1.jpg" width="200" height="160" alt="">
      <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-72deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 147px;" src="images/truck2.jpg" width="213" height="160" alt="">
      <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-144deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 120px;" src="images/truck3.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="">
      <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-216deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 147px;" src="images/truck4.jpg" width="213" height="160" alt="">
      <img style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-288deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 122px;" src="images/truck5.jpg" width="238" height="160" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="stage" style="padding-left: 180px; height: 160px;">
<div id="spinner" style="-webkit-transform-origin: 180px 0 0;">
  <img onclick="showInfo(1)" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 160px;" src="images/truck1.jpg" width="200" height="160" alt="">
  <img onclick="showInfo(2)" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-72deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 147px;" src="images/truck2.jpg" width="213" height="160" alt="">
  <img onclick="showInfo(3)" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-144deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 120px;" src="images/truck3.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="">
  <img onclick="showInfo(4)" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-216deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 147px;" src="images/truck4.jpg" width="213" height="160" alt="">
  <img onclick="showInfo(5)" style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(-288deg) translateX(180px); padding: 0 0 0 122px;" src="images/truck5.jpg" width="238" height="160" alt="">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showInfo(truck) {
    switch (truck) {
      case 1:
        document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = "truck1";
        break;
      case 2:
        document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = "truck2";
        break;
      case 3:
          document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = "truck3";
          break;
      case 4:
          document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = "truck4";
          break;
      case 5:
          document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = "truck5";
          break;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Shows a description within a div somewhere else, hope this helps :P